# Is it possible to show blog view counter with information Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, github, google-analytics, jekyll, google-analytics-api

I have a static blog using Jekyll hosted on GitHub. I have set up Google Analytics for it and works well enough.

Now I want to show how many people viewed each post in my blog. I found [Google Analytics JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) to get the information. But it seems that this API uses OAuth for data access. So I think this might not be the API I needed.

Is it possible to do so with Google Analytics? I don't have any server since it's hosted on GitHub.

Comment: [Have you seen this](https://gist.github.com/mtowers/5986576)

Comment: @hex494D49 I think this still needs Ruby server, doesn't it?

Comment: Never used it, but the GA super proxy can publish GA data and works with the real time api: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks! It works after much effort. You really helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by [Google Analytics superProxy](https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-super-proxy) as suggested in the comment of @EikePierstorff.

I wrote [a blog on it](http://zhangwenli.com/blog/2014/08/05/page-view-from-google-analytics-for-your-blog/).

Here's the main idea.

I first build a project on Google App Engile, with which I authenticate for the access of my Google Analytics. Then a URL of query (which can be pageview of certain pages) is generated in JSON format. I can set the refresh rate on this GAE project so that the JSON file can be updated from Google Analytic.

Sounds almost perfect to me. Thank you all guys for help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't query the Google Analytics API without authorization by someone, that's the most important thing to remember.

It's certainly possible to display Google Analytics data on your website to users who don't have access to your account, but in order to do that, someone with access to the account needs to authorize and get an access token in order to run queries.

Normally this is done server side, and once you have a valid access token you can query the API client side (to display charts and graph, etc.). Access tokens are typically valid for 1 hour, so if you want to have your website up all the time, you'll also have to deal with refreshing the access token once it expires.

Now, since you're using Github Pages and don't have a back end, which means all the authorization will need to happen client side. While it's technically possible to do the same thing client side as server side, it's generally not a good idea because private data like your client secret, refresh token, etc. will be visible in the source code.

Applications that do auth client side typically don't authorize on behalf of a user. They require the users themselves to go through an auth flow for security reasons (as I just explained), but that would mean those users 1) have to log in, and 2) can only see the analytics data they have access to, which probably isn't what you want.

--

What you **can** do is run reports periodically yourself and export that data to a Google Spreadsheet. Google Spreadsheets allow you to embed charts and graphs of data as an `<iframe>` in external pages, so that might be an option.

At the end of the day, if you can't authorize server side you'll have to come up with some kind of workaround to make this happen.

Here are a few possibly helpful links that might point you in the right direction:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic